# doubt on H infinity mixed sensitivity control synthesis

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, pi-controller

I'm applying loop shaping on a MIMO system. We know that the sensitivity is $S = (I+PC)^{-1}$  and the control effort is given by 
$CS = C(I+PC)^{-1}$.

Through loop shaping theory for $H_\infty$ I'm trying to synthesize a controller such that

\begin{equation}
\left\|\begin{array}{c} W_s S\\ W_u CS\end{array} \right\|_\infty \leq \gamma
\end{equation}

so if $\gamma \leq 1$ we have that 
$\left\|S\right\|_\infty \leq \left\|W_s^{-1}\right\|_\infty$ and $\left\|CS\right\|_\infty \leq \left\|W_u^{-1}\right\|_\infty$.

My question is the following. Since $S$ is a MIMO transfer matrix, and I chose $W_s$ and $W_u$ to be diagonal weighting functions the proper channel-by-channel analysis should verify that

$\left\|S(i,:)\right\|_\infty \leq W_{s,i}^{-1}$

or I'm imposing

$\left\|S(i,i)\right\|_\infty \leq W_{s,i}^{-1}$?

where $i$ is the specific error channel I want to constrain frequency-wise. In other words if the plant is not diagonal and I choose diagonal weighting functions, are those weighting functions representing an upper bound for the specific output channels or for the I/O combinations of the sensitivity? Thanks!